# Why does only one (the last) XML file is saved?

Tags: php, xml

I use this below to save me the contents of the XML addresses I have in array. However only one XML is saved, specifically the last one. What am I missing here?

```
$filenames = array('xml url','xml url','xml url');

foreach( $filenames as $filename) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $filename );
$xml->asXML("test.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filenames = array('xml url','xml url','xml url');

foreach( $filenames as $key => $filename) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( $filename );
    $xml->asXML('test' . $key. '.xml');
}
```

That should save the files sequentially as `test0.xml`, `test1.xml`, `test2.xml` and so on.

If you want all your loaded XML URL's to be appended to a single file, you can do something like this:

```
$filenames = array('xml url','xml url','xml url');

$fullXml = array();
foreach( $filenames as $key => $filename) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( $filename );

    // Convert the simplexml object into a string, and add it to an array
    $fullXml[] = $xml->asXML();
}

// Implode the array of all our xml into one big xml string
$fullXml = implode("\n", $fullXml);

// Load the new big xml string into a simplexml object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($fullXml);

// Now we can save the entire xml as your file
$xml->asXml('test.xml');
```

Comment: I see, Is there any way to create only one file ?

Comment: I tried both methods. I don't have any problem with the first, but the second gives me errors. `Entity: line 56: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document` `Entity: line 57: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document` and other. The XMLs I am trying to get are feedburner RSS

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be opening each XML file, then saving them in the same location. File 1 is written, then File 2 overwrites it, then File 3... In short, the last file will overwrite the previous ones, and therefore "only the last one is saved".

What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You save them all as the same name, so of course the earlier ones will be lost.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a question though. In my page, I load a lot of external rss and output some contents. If I save them on the server, the loading will be quicker ?

Comment: I just checked that. The difference in speed is amazing.

Comment: If that's all you want to do then you don't need to put them through the XML parser; just download them directly.